# In Symfony, in which directory do I put my custom class?

Tags: php, symfony1

In my symfony application I would like to create custom php class. And access that class via back end and front end. Can someone show me which folder should I put that class and how to access it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put it in the `/lib` folder. There it'll be autoloaded by Symfony .

It's recommended to create subfolders in `/lib` to group classes/files by their function.
(for example a directory `/lib/routing` for classes that concern the routing).